# get only rendered component color variables from global color variable file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm

**color_variables.css:**

```
[data-theme='default'] {
  --avatar_bg: #000;
  --avatar_text: #fff;
  --avatar_border: red;
  --button_bg: blue;
  --button_text: #fff;
  --button_border: darkblue;
  --modal_widget_bg: orange;
  --footer_bg: yellow;
  --footer_text: #000; 
}
```

**avatar.css:**

```
.avatar {
  background-color: var(--avatar_bg);
  color: var(--avatar_text);
  border: 1px solid var(--avatar_border);
}
```

**button.css:**

```
.button {
  background-color: var(--button_bg);
  color: var(--button_text);
  border: 1px solid var(--button_border);
}
```

We have a single color_variables.css file for all components (avatar, button, footer, tab, etc..,). For eg: I have a page that renders only avatar component, it renders avatar.js and avatar.module.css file. So, other unnecessary components will not be rendered in that page.

My question is, Is there any way to pick the used variables from color_variables.css file. I said I have a page that renders avatar component only. So, I want to get the color value of these three variables (--avatar_bg, --avatar_text, --avatar_border) from color_variables.css file. I don't need button color variables and other unnecessary color variables in that page. Is there any way to pick only needed color variables? (I don't wish to split that global variable file)

Comment: I don't see how this could be done automatically as the system doesn't know at load time whether any of the other variables might be used later on, e.g. by JS setting them for an element.

Comment: I think you may need to use some framework like Tailwindcss if you need to achieve this.

Comment: You can create a js file. colorvar.js and assign the values to these variables. and then you can import script anywhere you want. and use those variables value

Answer (score 1):

you can send from the parent component only the CSS variables you need and let it handle "reading" and assigning the variables to the components that need them

Answer (score 0):

you just need to import color_variables.css in your index.js or app.js so all other component detect your css from color_variables.css